# Connecting Linux client to 2 seperate networks

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, vpn, remote-desktop

Hi I was wondering if the following setup would work.
[image: My Network]

I am trying to accomplish the following.

Connect to VPN server from outside my network and then VNC or RDP and possibly SSH into the other raspberry pi and have access to resources shared on SMB on Neighborhood LAN.

I dont need internet connectivity from the Neighborhood LAN just access to network resources like SMB shares.

Do I need to set up any special routes for this to work?

Thanks

Comment: if the neighborhood lan its a single private IP network, then you should be fine, though you will need a route for .1.x through .10.1 on any systems inside .10.x lan. if there are additional networks inside the neighborhood lan, you will need routes for those as well, on devices both in .10.x and .1.x . if you don't have a specific route to a host on the neighborhood lan, you won't be able to use the default route to just send traffic upstream, because that is being used by the path to the Internet.

Comment: Another more annoying hiccup can be DNS over VPN links. hopefully you don't have issues there.